# monthCalender date format to yyyy-mm-dd : c#

Tags: c#, mysql, date, format

I have a database in MySQL. Now i want to insert value for a attribute of type data in in the database which is of the format yyyy-mm-dd.

I will be getting date from 'monthCalender'. Currently i am getting the date in format mm/dd/yyyy by using this code.

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

How should i convert the format?

also i feel its weird for MySQL to ask for such a format. So i may be wrong. by the way am using XAMPP for the database.

Comment: Use sql-parameters and `datetime`s.

Comment: @TimSchmelter havent used it before. Can you give an example.

Comment: Google "C# Parameterized Queries" for more information. You shouldn't be specifying the string representation of a date in your DB access layer. It sounds like you've got an SQL injection problem in your app.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Its ok, this is just a college project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

[DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) accepts custom format as argument