# How do I change the format of the date outputted from monthCalendar

Tags: c#

My code as of now

```
monthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
String date = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString();
date = date.Substring(0, 10);
DateLabel.Text = "Date Selected : " + date;
```

When it outputs the date selected, it outputs as 2/9/2020.  How do I change this so it outputs as 02/09/2020, so that all of the dates are the same amount of characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [monthCalender date format to yyyy-mm-dd : c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735319/monthcalender-date-format-to-yyyy-mm-dd-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start` is a `DateTime` - so specify the format you want when you convert it to a string. For example, you *could* write:

```cs
DateTime start = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;
string formattedStart = start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Note that that's a US-centric date format though, whereas your current code just uses the default formatting pattern for the current culture. If you want an unambiguous, fixed-width date pattern I'd suggest using ISO-8601 instead:

```cs
DateTime start = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;
string formattedStart = start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```